# How to switch between RestControllers depending on HTTP header values?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, api-versioning

We are considering using a header field to specify the REST API version in our spring boot application.

How can we tell spring boot to redirect calls depending on a header value?

I am dreaming about something like this:

```
@Path("/my/rest/path")
@HeaderMapping(headerName="ApiVersion", headerValue="V1")
public class V1Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public String myMethod() {
    }
}

== and ==

@Path("/my/rest/path")
@HeaderMapping(headerName="ApiVersion", headerValue="V2")
public class V2Controller {

    @GetMapping
    public String myMethod() {
    }
}
```

for HTTP requests like these:

```
GET /my/rest/path HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
ApiVersion: V1

== or ==

GET /my/rest/path HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
ApiVersion: V2
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
@Path("/my/rest/path")
public class V1Controller {

    @GetMapping(headers = "ApiVersion=V1")
    public String myMethod() {
    }
}

== and ==

@Path("/my/rest/path")
public class V2Controller {

    @GetMapping(headers = "ApiVersion=V2")
    public String myMethod() {
    }
}
```

PS: Not yet tested, but seen in [a Spring boot tutorial](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-versioning-for-rest-services#custom-headers-versioning).

Answer (score 1):

Yeap exactly: 
e.g

```
PUT method #1
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/foo", 
headers="returnType=Foo")
public @ResponseBody Foo updateFoo(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
fooService.update(foo);
}

//PUT method #2
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/foo", 
headers="returnType=FooExtra")
public @ResponseBody FooExtra updateFoo(@RequestBody FooExtra fooExtra) {
fooService.update(fooExtra);
}
```

Here you get documentation : 
[adding custom header](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/client.htm#RESTF168)